# Laravel 5.5 API Authentication (Passport) - cross-env: not found error, when i run npm run dev

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I have tried to implement laravel passport authentication in my project, but it's not working. Initially, i have installed laravel5.5 with other configuration and file permissions all the stuff.

To implement passport authentication I have followed laravel documentation [Document Url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport)

Following steps, I have done,

1. `composer require laravel/passport`
2. `php artisan migrate`
3. `php artisan passport:install`
4. I have added this line App\User

   use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
   use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
5. Routes Added in AuthServiceProvider file inside the boot function

   `Passport::routes();`
6. Inside the config/auth.php file, I have changed API driver as passport
7. `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components`
8. Inside this file resources/assets/js/app.js

   Vue.component(
   'passport-clients',
   require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
   );

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

9. `npm run dev`

When running this command I'm getting an error

> $ npm run dev
>
> @ dev /var/www/html/local/laravel5.5
>   npm run development
>
> @ development /var/www/html/local/laravel5.5
>   cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: 1: cross-env: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-98-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/sysadmin/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/home/sysadmin/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/local/laravel5.5/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-98-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/sysadmin/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/home/sysadmin/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run development
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/local/laravel5.5/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

You must run in cmd/terminal, from your project folder

```
npm install --save
```

and then

```
npm run dev
```